# Xamarin - Push Notification, OnMessageReceived triggers multiple times, loading multiple pages

Tags: xamarin.forms, push-notification, navigation

Guys im having an issue,

I want to load a page that displays the push notification string content but the OnReceivedMessage() gets triggered an increasing number of times equal to the amount of times I go to the DisplayPage and back.

So first time I run, the OnRevceivedMessage triggers, opens the DisplayPage() that i close and return to the previous page through PopAsync(). The second time I send notification with Postman and do a cycle to load DisplayNotificationPage and then back, the OnReceivedMessage() triggers twice, then 3 times etc for every run.

What is going on? I think it has to do something with subscribing.. how can i fix this?

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class NotificationReceivingPage : ContentPage
    {
        public NotificationReceivingPage ()
        {
            InitializeComponent ();
        }


        protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();
            MessagingCenter.Subscribe<object, string>(this, App.NotificationReceivedKey, OnMessageReceived);
        }

        private void OnMessageReceived(object sender, string incomingNotificationBody)     // gets triggered x1, x2, x3... and so on
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(incomingNotificationBody))
            {
                Navigation.PushAsync(new NotificationDisplayPage(incomingNotificationBody));
            }         
        }

        protected override void OnDisappearing()
        {
            base.OnDisappearing();
            MessagingCenter.Unsubscribe<object>(this, App.NotificationReceivedKey);
        }


[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class NotificationDisplayPage : ContentPage
    {
        ISimpleAudioPlayer soundPlayer;
        private static string incomingMessage = null;

        //default constructor
        public AlarmDisplayPage ()
        {
            InitializeComponent ();
        }

        // overloaded constructor that receives incoming notification body
        public AlarmDisplayPage(string messageBody)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            if (messageBody != null)
            {
                incomingMessage = messageBody;
            }

            //alarm to sound on incoming message
            var assembly = typeof(AlarmDisplayPage);
            alertHeader.Source = ImageSource.FromResource("ShakeAlarmRR1.Assets.Images.test-event-header.png", assembly);
        }


        protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();

            stopAlarmButton.IsEnabled = true;

            //initialize soundplayer
            soundPlayer = Plugin.SimpleAudioPlayer.CrossSimpleAudioPlayer.Current;
            soundPlayer.Load(GetStreamFromFile("alarm.mp3"));

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(incomingMessage))
            {
                setEventDetails();

                //play the alarm
                soundPlayer.Play();
            }    

        }

        protected override void OnDisappearing()
        {
            base.OnDisappearing();
            soundPlayer.Stop();
            incomingMessage = null;
        }


        private Stream GetStreamFromFile(string mediaFilename)
        {
            var assembly = typeof(App).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
            var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("ShakeAlarmRR1.Assets.Sounds." + mediaFilename);
            return stream;
        }

        private void stopAlarmButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            stopAlarmButton.IsEnabled = false;

            Navigation.PopToRootAsync();
        }

        private void setEventDetails()
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(incomingMessage))
            {
                labelEventType.Text = incomingMessage;
            }
            else
            {
                labelEventType.Text = "No Data";
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Try set `incomingMessage = null;` or another one-time check after you process your message in the OnAppearing event. Maybe it bugs firing onappearing without ondissapering inbetween. If this is the case also move Subscribe to the constructor.

Comment: @NickKovalsky I managed to solve it by adding a isSubscribed boolean class variable. This boolean keeps track whether the page is already subscribed or not and using it,  the subscribing and unsubscribing is only done depending on the current subscription status of the page. The problem was I subscribing every time OnAppear() was triggered, so subscribing took place multiple times. What I did not know was that subscribing multiple times results in OnMessageReceived() being triggered multiple times.